# How to bind a NSTextField editable binding in a NSTableView?

Tags: macos, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have a view based NSTableView with content bound to an NSArrayController. I want the table to be editable only at certain times so I created a boolean property in my viewcontroller to indicate when the fields can/cannot be edited.  This works fine for other fields in the UI but not in the NSTableView. If I bind the text field inside the table cell view editable binding to my viewcontroller's editable property then Xcode hangs while compiling the storyboard and I find a runaway ibtoold process running on my mac even after stopping the build.

A table cell view's content is normally bound to objectValue. Does the editable binding also need to be bound to objectValue?

Comment: I noticed the same issue and regard it as a bug. A workaround is to use the data source and delegate protocol methods rather than `NSArrayController`.